# CodeMagic xcode-project use-profiles failure

Tags: ios, react-native, codemagic, react-native-fast-image

I try to build an ios app with codeMagic

```yaml
    scripts:
      - name: Install dependencies
        script: |
            yarn install
      - name: Install CocoaPods dependencies
        script: |
            cd ios && pod install
      - name: Set up provisioning profiles settings on Xcode project
        script: |
          sudo gem install xcodeproj
          sudo xcode-project use-profiles
      - name: Build ipa for distribution
        script: |
          xcode-project build-ipa \
            --workspace "$CM_BUILD_DIR/ios/$XCODE_WORKSPACE" \
            --scheme "$XCODE_SCHEME"
```

But I have this: Failed to set code signing settings for node_modules/react-native-fast-image/ios/FastImage.xcodeproj. It happens at this step:

```bash
sudo xcode-project use-profiles
```

Answer (score 1):

To anyone having this issue use this

```bash
xcode-project use-profiles --project ios/*.xcodeproj
```